# How can I create one rewrite to handle these multiple URLs using web.config?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, web-config

Here is an example of my rewrites (which are working correctly) that are designed to remove index.cfm from the URLs.

However, rather than having multiple rewrites like below, I would like to have just one that handles them all.

I was thinking there must be a regex formula that would match this pattern so that I can have just one rule.

```
<rule name="Remove index.cfm from About Us" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="index.cfm$" />
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=8467" />  
    </conditions>  
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com?page=8467" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Remove index.cfm from Biography Page" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="index.cfm$" />
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=8469" />  
    </conditions>  
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com?page=8469" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Remove index.cfm from Video Page" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="index.cfm$" />
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=8473" />  
    </conditions>  
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com?page=8473" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I wish I could explain better, but I am used to .htaccess and not web.config.

```
<rule name="Remove index.cfm from URLs" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="index.cfm$" />
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=([0-9]+)" />  
    </conditions>  
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/?page={C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```